# Как изменить сервер (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB на .\SQLEXPRESS?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, database-first

Использую для БД технологию EFCore, возникают ошибки.
Вот к примеру код в Package Manager Controle Код:

> 'PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Server= (localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=helloappdb;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.
> SqlServer Build started...
> Build succeeded.
> The specified deps.json C:\User... <Ошибка здесь

Comment: Какие ошибки возникают? / У вас установлен SQLEXPRESS?

Comment: Вот к примеру  код в Package Manager Controle  Диспетчер пакетов                                      После успеха выводит:   'The specified deps.json [C:\Users\'    Код>                                                                                                
 'PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=helloappdb;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Build started...
Build succeeded.
The specified deps.json [C:\Users\'

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив текст ошибок в него.

Comment: _Build succeeded_ - Где ошибка-то?

Comment: После 'Build succeeded' выводит: 'The specified deps.json [C:\Users\'